# Menu pushed the image down in mobile version using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here is desktop version of navigation bar

[image]

here is the image when it screen size comes to mobile version after clicking on hamburger button

[image]

I want when I click on the hamburger for the menu to open but if it doesn't get pushed down it will be open over the image.

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  outline: none !important;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.navbar-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
  height: 3px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid wow fadeIn">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <a class="navbar-brand wow fadeInLeft" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="160px" height="60px"></a>
    <button aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto wow fadeInRight">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><strong>HOME </strong><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><strong>ABOUT</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><strong>SERVICES</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><strong>PORTFOLIO</strong></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#"><strong>CONTACT US</strong></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
<header id="home-section" class="mb-3">
  <img src="img/banner.jpg" alt="" width="100%">
</header>
```

Where did I make a mistake? Which css property or bootstrap class is need to be added?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap collapsed menu not pushing content down when expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22564817/bootstrap-collapsed-menu-not-pushing-content-down-when-expanded)

Comment: Please provide your all css on the logo and navigation menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.navbar-fixed-top` class to fixed it on mobile

Comment: thanks for giving me this idea i m totally forgotten this class

Answer (score 0):

In Mobile version, keep the hamburger dropdown menu `position: absolute;` so that the menu dropdown will appear above the image

Use media queries for mobile version and execute the code. For example,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .navbar-collapse{
        position: absolute;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not working the menu items shows over the icon and the all items are transparent